# ViewBinding is not able to use views from the layout file

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm building a Resume Builder App. For that I have to use view binding. In my app everting works well I'm able to create a view binding object of the variable with a particular layout. But when I call the views from the binding variable it's working in the .kt file but not while running the app. Binding object shows the view. But when I run the app it's not working as stated in the code.

```
class EducationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityEducationBinding
    private lateinit var toolbar : Toolbar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityEducationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_education)

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_eduction_activity)
        setUpToolbar()
    }

    private fun setUpToolbar(){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val actionBar = supportActionBar
        if (actionBar!=null){
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_button_action_bar)
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        }

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
    }
```

The code above is working with : setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

but when I use, setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarEducationActivity). It's not working while running the app. There is no error or anything.
I didn't understand the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using databinding but finding the views by id?

Comment: Instead of using   toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_eduction_activity)                               setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
Use      setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar). It should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're inflating your layout *twice*:

```
binding = ActivityEducationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_education)
```

The `inflate` call inflates your layout XML, builds a view hierarchy, and stores references to that in the `binding` object.

Then the `setContentView` call with a layout reference inflates *another, completely separate* view hierarchy and displays it.

So you have two sets of views, one is visible and the other isn't. The ones in `binding` are the ones that aren't being displayed - the user can't see or interact with them, so they're pretty much useless. That's why things aren't working when you try to set stuff up with the views in `binding`.

Using `findViewById` instead is implicitly calling it on the Activity's `view` hierarchy, i.e. the stuff that's displayed. That way you get a reference to the `Toolbar` that's actually on-screen, instead of the stray one in `binding`. So when you set things up with that one, you actually see it working!

---

So to solve it, you need to ensure you're inflating your layout **once**, and then make everything use that. There's two common ways to do it:

```
// inflate your Binding class, and pass the resulting layout to setContentView to display
binding = ActivityEducationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
// this root property is the inflated view hierarchy
setContentView(binding.root)
```

or

```
// use setContentView with a layout resource, and let it inflate the views as normal
setContentView(R.layout.activity_education)
// now that the 'view' property for the Activity has been set with the inflated layout,
// you can grab that and -bind- its views to the properties in your Binding class
binding = ActivityEducationBinding.bind(view)
```

The `bind` call is basically what happens with `inflate`, except you're skipping the inflation step because you already have an inflated layout.

---

You can use either approach - I prefer the first because you only specify the layout resource *once* by referencing the appropriate binding class. Then you just pass whatever you inflate to `setContentView` for display. With the second approach, you have to make sure the Binding class you use matches the layout resource ID you pass into `setContentView`. Not a huge deal and sometimes one is more convenient than the other!

The important thing though is that in both cases, you only *inflate* something **once**. Then everything is using the same set of views, and nothing weird is going on. If you ever find yourself inflating more than once, and you don't have *a very specific reason for doing it*, then that's a warning sign!

Answer (score 0):

Why are u using findViewByID's with viewBinding?

Your code should be like this

**--> KOTLIN**

```kotlin
class EducationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityEducationBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityEducationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setUpToolbar()
    }

    private fun setUpToolbar(){
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        val actionBar = supportActionBar
        if (actionBar!=null){
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_button_action_bar)
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        }

        binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
    }
```

Do mark this as the answer if this helps.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It's not working that's why I have to use findViewById().

Comment: This issue still exists, unable to find any solution, had to use findViewById.